# How to structure a csv in order to have a readable json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I'm getting a bit confused on how I should be structuring the csv file, currently I do:

[image]

But that when I parse it gives me a json like:

```
[
  {
    "20": "15",
    "New York": "Singapore",
    "Employee": "Employee"
  }
]
```

How should I be structuring the csv to correctly output the related values'

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZFvQ/1452/) to play around

Comment: Don't have a csv file at the moment, but have you tried changing `for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)` to `for(var i=0;i<rows.length-1;i++)`?

Comment: Your CSV doesn't have a first row with column names; the output shows it expects them.

Comment: @AlonEitan nope, same thing

Comment: @AlonElton you are right, sorry. Just came from some PHP questions. I removed that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSV file is basically just a list of comma separated values on multiple lines.

All you have to do is go through your CSV String and populate a Javascript Object from it.

The basic logic behind this quick function is to `split` your String on every `newline` then split it again on every `,` :

```js
const csv = `New York,Employee,20
Singapore,Employee,15`;

const csvToObject = s => s.split('\n').map(line => line.split(','));

console.log(csvToObject(csv));
```

Comment: that looks like it is working, trying to apply it to my jsfiddle with no luck tho, where should I use it while having                         
                        `var arr = (dataArray);
                        $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  '));`

Comment: looks almost perfect, just having `[
  [
    "New York",
    "Employee",
    "20\r"
  ],
  [
    "Singapore",
    "Employee",
    "15"
  ]
]` why  \r` ?

Comment: @rob.m You can `split('\r\n')` instead or `replace('\r','')` if you feel the need to.

Comment: tried `$("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(res, null, '  ')).replace('\r','');

Comment: but i still get /r in the output

Comment: @rob.m You need to replace it before my `.split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
CT,TY,VA
NY,EMP,20
AL,EMP,10
```

The above csv format results in right formated JSON.The first row specifies the title or the key in JSON for each column.

So give a name as it suits you in the first row and then the resulting JSON will come out as linked to the first row.

**Or hardcode the keys in an array like this `var firstRowCells = ['firstKey','secondKey','thirdKey'];`**

```js
$(function () {
    var firstRowCells = ['firstKey','secondKey','thirdKey'];
    var csv = $("#fileUpload").val();

    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\r\n");

                    if(rows.length>0){

                        var dataArray = new Array();
                        for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
                        {
                            var cells = GetCSVCells(rows[i], ",");
                            var obj = {};
                            for(var j=0;j<cells.length;j++)
                            {
                                obj[firstRowCells[j]] = cells[j];
                            }
                            dataArray.push(obj);
                        }

                        $("#dvCSV").html('');
                        var arr = (dataArray);
                        $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  '));
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});

function GetCSVCells(row, separator){
    return row.split(separator);
}
```

```css
#dvCSV {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" name="upload"/>
  <hr />
<div id="dvCSV"></div>
```

Comment: I've added the top label on each cell city - empl - num then I upload the cv file and i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: firstRowCells is not defined",`

Comment: @rob.m I've edited the answer I miss spelled the word